# My sp executes with no errors but the additional records are not in the table

Tags: sql-server

The table has an automated identity number. Below is my sp.  What could be the problem?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Append Samples Sent Nonwater Paragroups]
@Enter_FCOC_Number VARCHAR(20),
@Enter_SOW_MATRIX VARCHAR(20)
AS
INSERT INTO [Samples Sent]
     ([Client Sample ID],[LCOC Number],[SOWNumber],ParagroupID)
SELECT [Planned Samples].[Client Sample ID], [Planned Samples].[FCOC Number], [Project Task Stations].SOWNumber, [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParagroupID
FROM (([Planned Samples] INNER JOIN [Project Task Stations] ON ([Planned Samples].SOWNumber = [Project Task Stations].SOWNumber) AND ([Planned Samples].Station = [Project Task Stations].Station) AND ([Planned Samples].Projectid = [Project Task Stations].ProjectID)) INNER JOIN [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup] ON ([Project Task Stations].SOWNumber = [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].[SOW Number]) AND ([Project Task Stations].ProjectID = [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ProjectID)) LEFT JOIN [Samples Sent] ON [Planned Samples].[Client Sample ID] = [Samples Sent].[Client Sample ID]
GROUP BY [Planned Samples].[Client Sample ID], [Planned Samples].[FCOC Number], [Project Task Stations].SOWNumber, [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParagroupID, [Planned Samples].MedType, [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Matrix, [Planned Samples].VolatilesOnly, [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup, [Planned Samples].SampleType, [Samples Sent].[Client Sample ID], [refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Labcode
HAVING ((([Planned Samples].[FCOC Number])=@Enter_FCOC_Number) AND (([Planned Samples].MedType)<>'wq' And ([Planned Samples].MedType)<>'SQ') AND (([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Matrix) = @Enter_SOW_MATRIX AND ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Matrix)<>'WATER' And ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Matrix)<>'WIPE') AND (([Planned Samples].VolatilesOnly)='0') AND (([Samples Sent].[Client Sample ID]) Is Null)) OR ((([Planned Samples].MedType)<>'wq' And ([Planned Samples].MedType)<>'SQ') AND (([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].Matrix)<>'water') AND (([Planned Samples].VolatilesOnly)='1') AND (([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%voa%' Or ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%Ethan%' Or ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%acro%' Or ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%encore%' Or ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%moisture%' Or ([refProject/SOW/Title/Lab/Paragroup].ParameterGroup) Like '%dry_wt%') AND (([Samples Sent].[Client Sample ID]) Is Null));
```

Comment: likely that SELECT [Planned Samples].[Client Sample ID], [Planned Samples].[FCOC Number],...etc returns no records

Comment: As above, can you confirm that records exist with the criteria you are querying for?

Comment: I have confirmed that data exists in all the select tables. They just wont append to the specified table.

Comment: Run just the `SELECT` part, replace variables with the constants you are passing the SP. Do you get results?

Comment: Thanks!  That was the problem.